# Why are all IBOutlets set except _view?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, nib, iboutlet

I get the famous *loaded the "MyController" nib but the view outlet was not set* error. However I made sure, that the IBOutlet `view` is set.

Once the exception is thrown I hit a breakpoint. Below you can see that

- All IBOutlets are connected
- All IBOutlets are set

When unfolding UIViewController super-class, I can see that `_view` is 0x00000000 and obviously causes this exception.

[image: State]

#### Code (header)

```
@interface InfoDialogViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id episode;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *identifier;

@property (strong) IBOutlet UIView *regularSide;
@property (strong) IBOutlet UIView *flippedSide;

@property (weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *episodeCover;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UITextView *episodeTitle;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UITextView *episodeSummary;

- (IBAction)flip:(id)sender;

@end
```

#### Some notes

- The xib file contains three UIViews on its root level (Flipped, Regular, View)
- `InfoDialogViewController.m` file doesn't contain any methods (I don't do any funky by overriding)
- I am using this Controller in combination with `addChildViewController`.

Anybody has an idea what happens here and how I can fix it? Does ARC play some tricks on me?

Comment: I'm confused; your menu shows `searchDisplayController`, your debugger and code shows `InfoDialogViewController`!

Comment: check whether you are connected the View to Files Owner or not. Just right click on the View you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check:
1. The Class for your View Controller's View should be UIView
2. File owner should be your View Controller
3. Right CLick on File Owner, your view Outlet should be set.

If it is already solved, can u mention what solved your issue?